# How do I use JAXB @XmlValue in extended class?

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I have XML like this:

```
*<link:label xlink:type="resource" 
 xlink:label="label" 
 xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label" 
 xlink:title="title" xml:lang="en" id="label_id">
 Firm's symbol</link:label>*
```

I have three class in my domain:

1:Label

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "label",namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase")

public class Label extends Resource {

@Column(name = "value")
private String value;

public Label() {
}

@XmlValue
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

2:Resource

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Resource extends ExtendedLinkElement {


private String id_resource;
private String label;
private String role;
private String title;
private String type;
public Resource() {
}
}
@XmlAttribute( name = "label",namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}
@XmlAttribute( name = "role",namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

@XmlAttribute( name = "title",namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
@XmlAttribute( name = "type",namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
```

3:ExtendedLinkElement

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class ExtendedLinkElement  {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

public ExtendedLinkElement() {

}
```

But in unmarshal the `xml` file i get this error:
**The property or field value can not be annotated with `XmlValue` since it is a subclass of another XML-bound class**

I use moxy for jaxb RI and when i use `@xmlMixed` , return null in my attribute.

Comment: You can use `XmlAdapter`.

Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625797/make-use-of-xmlvalue-in-subclass

Comment: Tank u Rehman,i use adapter and it work.